# Add synced events to google calendar

Tags: java, android, calendar, google-calendar-api

I've created an android app that adds events to any of my google calendars. It works so far but the events that I create are only visible in my local calendar app and not on the web. Here is the code I use to insert the events:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
for (Date date : getDates()) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendar.getId());
    values.put(Events.TITLE, type.getName());
    values.put(Events.DTSTART, buildStartDate(date));
    values.put(Events.DTEND, buildEndDate(date));
    values.put(Events.ALL_DAY, 0);
    values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    Uri event = contentResolver.insert(
                    CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Inserted event: " + event.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The `caledar.getId()` returns the Id of the calendar I've selected previously. `buildStartDate` and `buildEndDate` creates the start and the end date and returns it as milli seconds. The `type.getName()` returns just a string that is used as the title.

Does anyone know why the events are only displayed in my local calendar app? When I use the calendar app to insert a new event, it is synced to the web, so the syncing does work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your `SyncAdapter`. It is required. The following code may help you.

```
static Uri asSyncAdapter(Uri uri, String account, String accountType) {
return uri.buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter(android.provider.CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER,"true")
    .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account)
    .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType).build();
```

}

See this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#sync-adapter) and also [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html).

Thanks!